# Tkinter's place() function is cutting off the first letter of an label

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Image of what's happening above:

[image]

The second output is the actual expected result. Both are placed the same but processed with different functions.

The first one (problem) is being placed like this:

```py
gui = Gui(Tk())

class ModifiedPrint:
    def __init__(self):
        self.old = sys.stdout

    def write(self, text):
        sys.stdout = self.old
        Label(gui.root, text=text, fg='white', bg='black').place(x=0, y=gui.Space-30)
        sys.stdout = self

    def flush(self):
        self.old.flush()


sys.stdout = ModifiedPrint()

gui.root.mainloop()
```

While the second one `Label(self.root, text=eval(cmd), fg='white', bg='black').place(x=x, y=y)`.

From my research it's **not an value problem** / something else cutting it off. I've tried to place it far away and it's still being cut-off. As well adding a space (like ' ' + text) changes nothing, h (first letter) is still being cut off.

Entire code: https://pastebin.com/EfshUvde

Comment: Instead of `.place` it will be much easier to use `.pack`.

Comment: Read up on the `anchor` option in the `place` command.  Though `place` is probably not the right choice here.

Answer (score 0):

The function is being called twice, the second time it's always going to be "\n"

This is what happens after print hello is inputted:

```py
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] 
['\n']
```

I've fixed it by checking if the function is being called the first or second time.

```py
class ModifiedPrint:
    def __init__(self):
        self.runs = 0
        self.old = sys.stdout

    def write(self, text):
        self.runs += 1
        if self.runs % 2 == 0: return
        self.runs = 1

        Label(gui.root, text=text, fg='white', bg='black').place(x=0, y=gui.Space-30)

    def flush(self):
        self.old.flush()
```

Comment: Instead of having `self.runs` as an `int`, wouldn't a `bool` be better? You can toggle it using `self.runs = not self.runs`